# Azure CosmosDB debugging stored procedure: making log readable

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, console.log

I'm working with CosmosDB stored procedures. I'm trying to debug one, but my log output will not empty or format. I tried adding `\n` and `\r\n` to the console.log() messages but still they are all on one line and spaces are interpreted as `%20`. The log messages from all previous executions remain in the console.log output. So they're just stacking on top of each other.

[image]

How do I write my stored procedure so that the log is readable and doesn't stack on top of the log messages from previous executions of the stored procedure?

It is very frustrating the lack of documentation for this.

Answer (score 2):

The log in URL-encoding. We will look into improving console.log in Portal, meanwhile can you use URL-decoders such as https://www.urlencoder.org/, would that work?

Comment: The issue is that every time I run the stored procedure, all of the console.logs get dumped into that tab on top of the output from previous executions. And they're encoded. I don't understand why Microsoft can't just make it work properly.